# Is there throttle in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm trying to find an operator in RxJava that will throttle in a specific way:

- Emits an element
- For a set period after the element has been emitted, all other emitted elements are filtered out

I can't seem to find one that matches this behavior.  I looked at some similar ones but none of them seem to be correct.

- `debounce`/`throttleWithTimeout` - emits the last element in a sequence of elements that were emitted with a short period between them
- `sample`/`throttleLast` which looks at set time intervals and emits the last element in each time interval.
- `throttleFirst` which looks at set time intervals and emits the first element in each time interval.  This seems to be the closest to what I want but isn't exactly the same.

Is there any RxJava operator that I can use that will match this?  It seems to be a useful use case.

Comment: There is a new [`ThrottleLatest`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#throttleLatest-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) operator in RxJava 2.1.14 just released. Please check if it fits your expected behavior.

Comment: Not exactly, but, after looking through those javadocs, I realized that `throttleFirst` was what I wanted.  Other documentation is a bit wrong, http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables

Comment: Yes the docs/wiki is a bit out of date, always consult with the javadoc first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[throttleFirst](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#throttleFirst-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) was what I was looking for.  I didn't realize initially because most of the documentation on the internet is slightly off (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html , https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables) .  The Javadocs is correct and where I found what I was looking for.